# Hats not showing on list

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2013

Some hats I earned a few hours ago are not showing in the popup to select them

Although they do show in the counter..

[image: Hats Popup on StackOverflow]

---

**Update**

They appear if I open the popup from meta but not from Stack Overflow (*where they were earned*).

[image: Hats Popup on Meta]

Comment: They might be slow to show up?  But doesn't really matter, they will be gone in 3 hours.

Comment: @psubsee2003 not sure about the slow to show.. they show if the popup is opened from meta but not if opened from the SO site.. regarding the fact that they will be gone, you are right.. still wanted to bring it up..

Comment: Yeah, that does seem odd, but you didn't add that tidbit until after I commented originally.  I'm still guessing this might be some sort of server side caching since they do show up on meta, just not on SO yet.

Comment: @psubsee2003 your are probably right !

Comment: Sounds like your browser got something cached a little too aggressively. Wait another 2 hours and it'll be fixed...